# Why can't I recur in a java java.lang.Enum generic type definition?

Tags: java, generics, enums

This is an academic question intended to better understand generics behave in this scenario.

The `Enum` type is described  as "the common base class of all Java language enumeration types". Its definition is:

```java
public abstract class Enum<E extends Enum<E>>
        implements Comparable<E>, Serializable {

}
```

Now, I could define a field with this definition:

```java
public class MyClass { 
   public Enum<MyEnum> field;
}
```

All fine. Now, take it one step further. Since `Enum<MyEnum>` is apparently equivalent to `MyEnum` that would leave me to believe that according to the definition I also could write:

```java
public class MyClass { 
   public Enum<Enum<MyEnum>> field;
}
```

But now the compiler actually stops me: `Type parameter 'java.lang.Enum' is not within its bound; should extend 'java.lang.Enum<MyEnum>>` which it does according to the definition since it still satisfies: `E extends Enum<E>`. Of course, there are all kinds of reasons why you would not allow such recurring (or perhaps better, incurring) construction, but the one given does feel wrong to me.

On the other hand, if I were to define a class like this (in analogue to the definition of the `Enum`)

```
public class Wrapper<T extends Number> { 
}
```

I would be able to write a class:

```java
public class MyClass { 
   // satisfies the upper bound
   public Wrapper<Integer> field1;

   // also satisfies the upper bound
   public Wrapper<Number> field2;
}
```

Am I overlooking something or is my analysis misguided?

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstand the problem, but can ```public MyEnum field``` work for you?

Comment: *"I could define a field with this definition: `public Enum<MyEnum> field`"* --- Why would you? Why not just define it as `public MyEnum field`, since `MyEnum extends Enum<MyEnum>`, and will be the **only** class ever to do so.

Comment: It is not about practical solutions. It's for understanding the language better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `Enum<Enum<MyEnum>>`, it makes `E` equal to `Enum<MyEnum>`.

The bound `E extends Enum<E>` therefore requires that `Enum<MyEnum>` must extend `Enum<Enum<MyEnum>>`, which it doesn't, and hence is rejected by the compiler.

---

Remember, `Enum` is the implicit superclass of an `enum`.

When you write `enum MyEnum { ... }`, what you get is really `class MyEnum extends Enum<MyEnum> { ... }`.

Which makes `E` equal to `MyEnum`.

The bound `E extends Enum<E>` therefore requires that `MyEnum` must extend `Enum<MyEnum>`, which it does, so the compiler is happy.

Comment: It took me some help to realize this. What you are saying in a relation `T extends SomeType<A>`, `T` can never be equal to `SomeType<B>`. It has to be either: `SomeType<A>` or `AnotherType<A>` where  `AnotherType<T>` is  class defined like  `public class AnotherType<T> extends SomeType<T>{...}`

Comment: @Sjaak Correct, and that is because of this: [Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>? Why are Java generics not implicitly polymorphic?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2745265/5221149)

Answer (score 6):

I take it this is an academic question. You're not actually writing code like this, you just want to understand the language better, right? Because in real code you'd of course simply write:

```
public MyEnum myField;
```

In that spirit—

> Since `Enum<MyEnum>` is apparently equivalent to `MyEnum`...

They're not equivalent. `MyEnum` is a *subclass* of `Enum<MyEnum>`. The autogenerated class is something like:

```
public final class MyEnum extends Enum<MyEnum> {
    ...
}
```

That means you can't keep expanding the declaration with `Enum<Enum<MyEnum>>`. You could write this, if you so desired:

```
public Enum<? extends Enum<MyEnum>> field;
```

That would compile, and the recursive possibilities end there.

> What I understand of an upper bound `X` in `T extends X` that it includes `X` and its subclasses. So `Enum<Enum>` should be allowed but it isn't.

Let's take a look at exactly what `E` is, the `E` from here:

```
public abstract class Enum<E extends Enum<E>>
```

When you write `Enum<Enum<MyEnum>>`, `E` is `Enum<MyEnum>`. Does this `E` match the constraint `E extends Enum<E>`? We need to substitute `E` with `Enum<MyEnum>`.

```
E extends Enum<E>?
^              ^

Enum<MyEnum> extends Enum<Enum<MyEnum>>?
^^^^^^^^^^^^              ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Now let's answer a couple related but subtly different questions:

- Does `MyEnum` extend `Enum<MyEnum>`? Yes. The autogenerated code I listed above shows this to be the case.
- Does `Enum<MyEnum>` extend `Enum<MyEnum>`? Yes. As you correctly describe in your `Number` example, a class is considered to be a subclass of itself as far as the `extends` keyword is concerned.
- And now the question we're concerned with here and now: Does `Enum<MyEnum>` extend `Enum<Enum<MyEnum>>`? No, it doesn't. This is the relation that would need to hold in order for the code you tried to work. It doesn't hold, and that's why your code doesn't compile.

Comment: Yes.. it is academic. And no.. most certainly I would not write code like this :) . But I'm involved in building an annotation processor which requires matching types. And we should be able to cover all scenarios. That's why I'd like to understand why my reasoning goes wrong. I need to think a more on your answer. Suppose a class:  `public class Wrapper<T extends Number> {}` . I would be able to create a field like this: `public class MyType{  public Wrapper<Number> field; }`  right? The upper bound  includes `Number` as well without resorting to wildcards.

Comment: I extended my example, just to make clear that it's an academic question. I understand that `MyEnum`is a subclass of `Enum<MyEnum> ` but that still satisfies the upper bound, right. Its inclusive (hence my example with `Number`).

Comment: So what I meant, the argument of: `Enum<Enum<MyEnum>>` is `Enum<MyEnum>` or raw `Enum`. What I understand of an upper bound X in `T extends X` that it includes X and its subclasses. So `Enum<Enum>` should be allowed but it isn't. And its here that I don't understand how it differs from my `Number` example.

Comment: Your answer is perfectly clear and it really helped me a lot. Thanks a lot for the time you invested. Though for me the aha moment came with the answer of @Andreas above. The part that confused was the `extends` bound. After all, (raw) `Enum` is in the bounds of `E extends Enum`. But it's the generic type parameter `X`  `Enum<X>` that spoils it.